# Problema Maratona: Calculadora (Nível 2)

Tags: c

Esse problema parece bem simples, entretanto meu código não submete de modo algum por acusar erro com alguma entrada aleatória.

O programa que gere a submissão da questão me dá algumas dicas:

> Verifique os seguintes pontos:
>
> - Lembre de colocar a saída com 3 casas decimais;
>   ***(isso eu já fiz)***
> - Os resultados parciais podem ser números reais e não somente inteiros;
>   ***(isso eu já fiz)***
> - Verifique os casos onde a operação não pode ser efetuada.
>   ***(adicionei a exceção da divisão por zero E add a exceção na escolha do carácter de operação)***

## Descrição da questão:

[image: Descrição da questão]

## Código

Ver também no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/sK0kQE)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double op(double num1, double num2, char c)//operacoes
{
 if(c == '/')//divisao
 {
    if(num2 == 0)
    {
        printf("operacao nao pode ser realizada");

        exit(1);
    }
    else
        num1 = (num1)/num2;
 }

 else if(c == '*')//multiplicacao
    num1 = (num1)*num2;

 else if(c == '-')//subtracao
    num1= num1 - num2;

 else if(c == '+')//soma
    num1 = num1 + num2;

 else if(c != '&')//se não for o caractere de finalização
 {
    printf("operacao nao pode ser realizada");//print o erro

    exit(1);
}

printf("%.3f\n", num1);//printa o resultado da operação de: num1 e num2

return num1;//retorna o resultado da operaçãos
}

void captar_e_op(double num1)//captar e operar
{
///VAR
double num2;//equivalente ao num2

char c;

///ENTRADA
scanf("%lf", &num2);

scanf(" %c", &c);

while(c != '&')//se o char não for '&', continue o loop
 {
    num1 = op(num1,num2,c);//num1 recebe(=) o resultado da operação de: "antigo num1"       e num2

    ///ENTRADA
    scanf("%lf", &num2);

    scanf(" %c", &c);
 }
}

int main()
{
  ///VARAVEIS
  char c;

 double num1, num2;

 ///ENTRADA
 scanf("%lf", &num1);

 scanf("%lf", &num2);

 scanf(" %c", &c);


 num1 = op(num1, num2, c);

 captar_e_op(num1);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Na verdade eu não sei identificar esse erro. Está relacionado com alguma entrada em que o resultado não retorna o esperado. Até agora todas minhas entradas retornaram o esperado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está usando `exit(1)` na função `op()` quando deveria utilizar `return`

Comment: O `exit()` esta la para os erros. Normalmente a função devolve o valor esperado.

Comment: Era exatamente isso amigo. Ao entrar num comando invalido, ou operação invalida o programa não encerrava como havia pensado;

Comment: `return num1;` ao invés de `exit(1);`

Answer (score 1):

Experimenta adicionar um *NewLine* nos dois printf de erro.

```
        printf("operacao nao pode ser realizada\n");
        //                                     ^^
```

Nalguns sistemas, a ausencia do *NewLine* faz com que a linha nao seja impressa ou reconhecida pelo programa parente.

Comment: Verdade. Alterei e submeti novamente. Mas o sistema ainda continua afirmando que o programa é refutável e dá as seguintes dicas:

Comment: Verifique os seguintes pontos:
* Lembre de colocar a saída com 3 casas decimais;
* Os resultados parciais podem ser números reais e não somente inteiros;
* Verifique os casos onde a operação não pode ser efetuada.

Answer (score 1):

Verifica os scanfs no main. Se o input não começar correctamente, o teu programa não dá mensagem de erro.

```
  if (scanf("%lf", &num1) != 1) { fprintf(stderr, "operacao nao pode ser realizada\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
  if (scanf("%lf", &num2) != 1) { fprintf(stderr, "operacao nao pode ser realizada\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
  if (scanf(" %c", &c) != 1) { fprintf(stderr, "operacao nao pode ser realizada\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
```

Comment: Alias deves **sempre** verificar os scanf().

Comment: Podes juntar os scanfs: `if (scanf("%lf%lf %c", &num1, &num2, &c) != 3) { /* erro */ }`

Comment: Obrigado por sua resposta! Nunca utilizei o scanf numa condição IF... WHILE... mas como que é o funcionamento do scanf nesses casos? quais valores o scanf pode retornar?

Comment: O `scanf()` devolve o numero de atribuicoes que executou ou `EOF` em caso de erro. Basicamente se o numero devolvido nao for igual ao numero de variaveis a atribuir valor, algo correu mal dentro do `scanf()`.